# htaccess RewriteRule to block php/html, allow all others...?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I write a RewriteRule for htaccess to block access to php/html (unless authenticated) and allow access to all other extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put a standard .htpassword auth inside a filesmatch attribute...

So...

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php)$">
AuthName "Private zone"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

That should cause any request to .html or .php to ask for a password, you must generate a valid .htpasswd file...

Comment: How would I do that in the RewriteRule format? RewriteRule \.(html|php)$ - [L] ...?

Comment: If you use a rewriterule how will you handle authentication ?  You could add a rewriterule to redirect all requests to a html or php page to a blocked message page, but how do you allow the people who have access?  You can possibly do it by ip, but not by username / password.

Comment: Something like "RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 12\.345\.67\.89 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 98\.76\.54\.3 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 67\.89\.0\.
RewriteRule ^.+\.(php|html)$ /blocked_page [L]  "

Comment: You should be able to use <FilesMatch> or <Files> where ever you are putting your mod_rewrite statements... in .htaccess or httpd.conf